# Context from ConstraintValidator doesn't return an instance of ExecutionContextInterface

Tags: validation, symfony

Symfony validator seems doesn't work. I've noticed that with the service `validator.email`. `ConstraintValidaotr::$context` doesn't return a `ExecutionContextInterface` instance, so I get the error

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "buildViolation" of class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EmailValidator".

With a custom constraint validator the same happens:

```
<?php
namespace MyAppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class Test extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Error message';

    public function getTarget()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'test_validator';
    }
}
```

and the validator

```
<?php
namespace MyAppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class TestValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $this->context->buildViolation('...')->addViolation('test');
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
validator.test:
    class: MyAppBundle\Validator\Constraints\TestValidator
    tags: 
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: test_validator }
```

I got the same error.
And this

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    echo get_class($this->context);
    $this->context->buildViolation('...')->addViolation('test');
}
```

on controller:

```
$this->get('validator.test')->validate('', new Test());
```

Says that context is an instance of `MyAppBundle\Validator\Constraints\TestValidator`. There's no sense.

I'm using Symfony 3.0.0.

Comment: This looks weird to me. Where do you make use of the `validator.email` service and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but following the documentation tutorial it doesn't worked.
This worked:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($value, new Test());
```